# How to prevent typo3 extension owl_slider from loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, typo3, typo3-extensions

I am using the owl_slider extension on my website: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/owl_slider/stable/

This extension is loading some jQuery version (which is btw bad proramming in my opinion). I want to have control which version of jQuery I want to load to avoid conflicts.

I cannot find a variable in the extension manual to not load jQuery. Is there some other way to stop the extension from loading jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the TypoScript contants for that extension. There is a constant titled `Include JQuery?` which you can disable. Or directly set this in your site extension constants:

```
plugin.tx_owlslider.includeJquery = 0
```

And yes, this is not documented well so feel free to add a pull request to fix this.

([See source](https://github.com/comsolit/owl_slider/blob/e15f8240cd98bc3f177247058405796dc5dbcfa0/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt#L89))